# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left((m+1)(m+2) \cdots (m+n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left((m+1)(m+2) \cdots (m+n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

My try:$$A=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left((m+1)(m+2) \cdots (m+n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Taking Natural log we get

$$\ln(A)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)$$

But i cant use Riemann Sum , Any idea?

Comment: There’s a $\log{1/n}$ missing

Comment: Similar recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365026/evaluate-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e-frac1n-n1n2n3%e2%8b%af2n-frac1n

Comment: I think it should be $\ln(A)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(m+k)$

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated: No. The $n$ in the denominator inside the log is the $\frac1n$ at the beginning of the limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$A=\frac{1}{n}\big((m+1)(m+2) \cdots (m+n)\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\Gamma (m+n+1)}{\Gamma (m+1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(nA)=\frac{1}{n}\big(\log (\Gamma (m+n+1))- \log (\Gamma (m+1)) \big)$$ Now, using the very first term of Stirling approximation for large $n$ you should get
$$\log(nA)=-1+\log(n)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$nA=e^{\log(nA)}=\frac n e +\cdots$$

**Edit**

If you want to the know the impact of $m$ on the result, yo need to add the next term in Stirling approximation and, using the same process, you should get
$$nA=\frac n e +\frac 1 e \left(\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (n)-\log (\Gamma (m+1))+\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi ) \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{m+k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
The limits are $\int_{m/n}^{1+m/n}$ as $n\to\infty$.