# Find the singular points of the differential equation $x^3(x - 1)y'' - 2(x - 1)y' + 3xy = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second order linear homogeneous equation
$$a_0(x)y'' + a_1(x)y'+ a_2(x)y = 0, x \in I \tag{1}$$
Suppose that $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are analytic at $x_0 \in I$. If $a_0(x_0) = 0$, then $x_0$ is a singular point for $(1)$.
**Definition**:  A point $x_0 \in I$ is a regular singular point for $(1)$ if $(1)$ can be written as
$$b_0(x)(x − x_0)^2y''+ b_1(x)(x − x_0)y'+b_2(x)y = 0, \tag{2}$$
where $b_0(x_0) \neq 0$ and $b_0$, $b_1$, $b_2$ are analytic at $x_0$.

The question is: Find the singular points of the differential equation $x^3(x - 1)y'' - 2(x - 1)y' + 3xy = 0$ and state whether they are regular singular points or irregular singular points.

---

I think, $x = 0$, irregular singular point, $x = 1$, regular
singular point. But, How can I prove this? Please proper guide me.

Comment: Hi Harry, I've formatted your question with MathJax. I really encourage you to learn how to do this for yourself. I'd also like to remind you of your [comment under your last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365026/evaluate-lim-n%e2%86%92%e2%88%9e-frac1n-n1n2n3%e2%8b%af2n-frac1n#comment6925207_3365026).

Comment: @ Theo. Thanks again.I am trying latex but not done properly. I am on my way to working with MathJax.

Comment: That's good! Feel free to edit your question to see how I've formatted it. That might help you figure it out a bit faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider the general homogeneous second order linear differential equation $$u''+P(x)u'+Q(x)u=0$$
> where $z \in D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

> The point $x_0 \in D$ is said to be an **ordinary point** of the above the given differential equation if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$.

> If either $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ fails to be analytic at $x_0$, the point $x_0$ is called a **singular point** of the given differential equation.

> A singular point $x_0$ of the given differential equation is said to be **regular singular point** if the function $(x-x_0)P(x)$ and $(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$ and **irregular** otherwise.

${}$

Here the given equation is $$x^3(x - 1)y'' - 2(x - 1)y' + 3xy = 0$$
$$\implies y''-\dfrac{2}{x^3}y'+\dfrac{3}{x^2(x - 1)}y=0$$
Here $~P(x)=-\dfrac{2}{x^3}~$and $~Q(x)=\dfrac{3}{x^2(x - 1)}~$.

Clearly $~x=0,~1~$ are singular points.

Again for the singular point $~x=0~$, $$(x-0)P(x)=-\dfrac{2}{x^2}\qquad \text{and}\qquad (x-0)^2Q(x)=\dfrac{3}{x-1}$$
Clearly $~(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)~$ is analytic at $~x_0=0~$ but $~(x-x_0)P(x)~$ is not. 
So $~x=0~$ is irregular singular point.

For the singular point $~x=1~$,  $$(x-1)P(x)=-\dfrac{2(x-1)}{x^3}\qquad \text{and}\qquad (x-1)^2Q(x)=\dfrac{3(x - 1)}{x^2}$$
Clearly both $~(x-x_0)P(x)~$ and $~(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)~$ are analytic at $~x_0=1~$. 
So $~x=1~$ is regular singular point.

Comment: @ nmsanta,I think this answer is correct and I am going with it. Am I right?

Comment: Have you faced any trouble in understanding my work ? I just doing things according to the definition.  @Harry Richie

Comment: No trouble. Clear like water..@ nmasanta

Comment: Only then my work will be well worth.